# Russian Text in HTML Email (In Russia)

Tags: unicode, cyrillic

I pasted in  my HTML code into Exact Target (email vendor), using this character set:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

The HTML body text was in Russian, and I tested it in several browsers and email clients - looked fine, until it got to Russia. See attached screenshot I was provided with. [Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYuwy.jpg)

Lots of UNICODE replacement characters.

What happened, and what do I do to make sure my Russian text works in Russia?

Comment: just because you pasted some valid unicode text doesn't mean it *STAYED* valid unicode the whole way. if ANY stage of the process uses a different charset, that unicode's going to get mangled.

Comment: Let me reach out to Exact Target tech support.

Thanks.